# Highlight menu when in a certain section

Tags: jquery, css, menu

I have a one page website in which I have 5 sections for eg. HOME, SERVICES CONTACT etc. I also Have a navigation menu. Now I want to make a way if I scroll to the service section the services menu will highlight same for contact and other section . How can I do that? thanks

Comment: javascript, jquery, css maybe. what have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use bootstrap's Scrollspy.js http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#scrollspy for example.